# Stripe Customer creation issues In Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used stripe for payment but customer not created. Please help me.

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
    :card => token,
    :plan => "1",
    :description => email
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have gem 'stripe' in your Gemfile.

Then try this from your console :

```
require "stripe" 
Stripe.api_key = "sk_test_KT791S3jh1y5t5xdnW6bjBln" 

Stripe::Customer.create( 
  :email => 'john@pinto.com'
  :description => "Customer for test@example.com", 
  :metadata => {
   "first_name" =>  "John", 
   "last_name" => "Pinto"
  }
)
```

Check this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=ruby#create_customer) for more info on creating customer.

Comment: On local machine customer create but on staging or uat environment it does not work.